# Count multiple colors in multiple excel files vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a multiple excel in a folder which has Yellow and red color filled in some cells

I need a excel log which will generate the file name count of yellow filed in each excel corresponding to that

eg:

Filename     Yellow     Red

1.xlsx         13        14
2.xlsx         5         10

can anyone help me.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using and will you need to count cell colours produced by 'manual' fill, conditional formatting or both/

Comment: Excel 2007, both manual and conditional formating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will log your Red and Yellow cells in a Sheet called "Log Sheet" in the workbook from which you run this code. Add/name this sheet and any formatting you require yourself.  Getting the cell colour of conditionally formatted cells is tricky but you may find help in [this article](http://www.bettersolutions.com/excel/EPX299/LI041931911.htm).  I have included a column in the Log Sheet to identify IF there are conditionally formatted cells in the worksheet but with no analysis or counts.  I have also included a column with the worksheet tab name.

This code analyses the cell colours within the sheets' UsedRange.  You will need to enter the path of your data files in the variable `dataFileFolder`.

[image: Log Sheet]

```
Sub countYellowRedCells()
Dim wbk As Variant
Dim wsLog As Worksheet, sht As Worksheet
Dim cCell As Range
Dim cfFlag As Boolean
Dim dataFileFolder As String
Dim redCount As Long, yellowCount As Long
Dim logRowEnd As Long, logCol As Long

Set wsLog = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log Sheet")

logCol = 2
redCount = 0
yellowCount = 0
cfFlag = False

dataFileFolder = "C:\......TestFiles\" 'ENTER YOUR PATH

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

wbk = Dir(dataFileFolder)

    Do Until wbk = ""
        Workbooks.Open dataFileFolder & wbk
            For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                For Each cCell In sht.UsedRange
                    If cCell.FormatConditions.count <> 0 Then cfFlag = True
                    Select Case cCell.Interior.Color
                        Case Is = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                            redCount = redCount + 1
                        Case RGB(255, 255, 0)
                            yellowCount = yellowCount + 1
                    End Select
                Next cCell

                With wsLog
                    logRowEnd = .Cells(Rows.count, logCol).End(xlUp).Row
                    .Cells(logRowEnd, logCol).Offset(1, 0).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Name
                    .Cells(logRowEnd, logCol).Offset(1, 1).Value = sht.Name
                    .Cells(logRowEnd, logCol).Offset(1, 2).Value = yellowCount
                    .Cells(logRowEnd, logCol).Offset(1, 3).Value = redCount
                    .Cells(logRowEnd, logCol).Offset(1, 4).Value = cfFlag
                End With

                'MsgBox (ActiveWorkbook.Name & " - Sheet: " & sht.Name & Chr(10) _
                & redCount & " Red cells." & Chr(10) & yellowCount & " Yellow cells.")
                redCount = 0
                yellowCount = 0
                cfFlag = False
            Next sht
        Workbooks(wbk).Close savechanges:=False
        wbk = Dir
    Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank u so much for solving my query